# Redirection at the end of the pipe (C shell)

Tags: c, shell, unix, pipe, io-redirection

I'm trying to make `ls | tr a b > text.txt`
I have piping done, but I can't add STDOUT to the end of the pipe (STDOUT in my case can be only in the last argument)

I mark the part of the code, in which redirection should be done, I think that file should be opened, and `dup2` method used, but I don't know in which way

Methods contains piping -

```
enum reqType { PIPE, STDOUT };

int spawn_proc (int in, int out, char** cmd) {
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork ()) == 0) {
        if (in != 0) {
          dup2 (in, 0);
          close (in);
        }
        if (out != 1) {
          dup2 (out, 1);
          close (out);
        }

      return execvp (cmd[0], cmd);
    }

  return pid;
}

void fork_pipes (int n, char** cmd[], enum reqType type) {
  int i;
  pid_t pid;
  int in, fd [2];

  in = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
      if(type == PIPE || i < n-2) {
        pipe (fd);

        spawn_proc (in, fd [1], cmd[i]);

        close (fd [1]);

        in = fd [0];
      }
      else if(type == STDOUT && i == n-2) {
            ///HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART?
      }
    }

  if (in != 0)
    dup2 (in, 0);

  execvp (cmd[i][0], cmd[i]);
}
```

EDIT 
in the marked by /// place I wrote

```
pipe(fd);
int out = open(cmd[n-1][0],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC);
spawn_proc(in, out, cmd[i]);
close(fd[1]);
```

Comment: use `open` to get a file descriptor to the redirected file and pipe to that. I would handle redirection prior to piping a command, you may want to examine the output of strace on your shell to see how it handles this

Comment: Look at the edited part of the question, please, something have to be changed there

Comment: I think that `in` in `spawn_proc(in, out, cmd[i])` should be `fd[0]` instead, i.e.: the *reading end* of the pipe.

Comment: But in the previous interation there is `in = fd[0]` so this is exactly the same

Comment: How are you actually calling the function `spawn_proc()`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question, I can tell you that I take `in` - stdout from last iteration, `out` - file path, `cmd[i]` - last command before file path

Comment: What is more important is the fact, that command `ls > text.txt` works, so the last iteration (what is added in edit) is well done, something isn't work when it comes to  send pipe result to the last iteration

Comment: you dont need a pipe for your redirection, it should be reading from the previous pipes read end. Just dup the file descriptor from `open` to stdout. And you may want to add permissions to your open call, eg. 0666.

Comment: @jakub1998 sorry, I meant how you actually were calling the `fork_pipes()` function, not `spawn_proc()`. So, how is `fork_pipes()` being parameterized when you call it?

Comment: @jakub1998 I've just provided a minimal example based on your original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that file should be opened, and `dup2` method used, but I don't know in which way

You are right about the mechanisms for implementing the redirection. It should be done on the process intended for `tr`, and before performing the overlay.

---

Let's go step by step:

```
ls | tr a b > text.txt
```

First create a pipe, then `fork()`.

From now on, there are **two** processes *running in parallel*, both of them will be eventually *overlaid* by means of `exec()`: one with the `ls` program, the other with the `tr` program.

### Process for `ls`:

1. Close the *reading end* of the pipe: this process will only write to the pipe.
2. `dup2()` the *writing end* of the pipe to `STDOUT`: what this process writes to `STDOUT` is being written to the pipe.
3. Perform the overlay: `exec()` with `ls`.

### Process for `tr`:

1. Close the *writing end* of the pipe: this process will only read from the pipe.
2. `dup2()` the *reading end* of the pipe to `STDIN`: what this process reads from `STDIN` is coming from the pipe.
3. In order to perform the **redirection** to the `text.txt` file, first `open()` the file `text.txt` for writing and with the flags `O_CREAT` and `O_TRUNC`, then `dup2()` the obtained file descriptor to `STDOUT`.
4. Perform the overlay: `exec()` with `tr`.

---

Note that, if the command were appending to `text.txt` instead of truncating it (i.e.: using `>>` instead of `>`):

```
ls | tr a b >> text.txt
```

You would have to use the flag `O_APPEND` instead of `O_TRUNC` when `open()`ing the `text.txt` file.

---

### Code Snippet

I've modified your code (also the interface of `fork_pipes()`). It's a minimal example that runs, I hope it helps.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int spawn_proc (int in, int out, char** cmd) {
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork ()) == 0) {
        if (in != 0) {
          dup2 (in, 0);
          close (in);
        }
        if (out != 1) {
          dup2 (out, 1);
          close (out);
        }

      return execvp (cmd[0], cmd);
    }

    return pid;
}

void fork_pipes (char** cmd[], const char *redirection) {
  int i, n;
  int in, out, fd[2];

  in = 0;

  // obtain n from the NULL terminated cmd array
  for (n = 0; cmd[n]; ++n)
    ;

  // process all but the last elemet of the pipe
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; ++i) {
        pipe(fd);
        spawn_proc(in, fd[1], cmd[i]);
        close(fd [1]);
        in = fd [0];
  }

  // process the last element of the pipe
    if (redirection) {
        out = open(redirection, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
        fchmod(out, 0666);
    } else
        out = STDOUT_FILENO;

    if (in != 0)
        dup2(in, 0);

    spawn_proc(in, out, cmd[i]);
}

int main()
{

    char *cmd1[] = {"ls", NULL};
    char *cmd2[] = {"tr", "a", "b", NULL};
    char **cmd[] = { cmd1, cmd2, NULL};

    // redirected to text.txt
    fork_pipes(cmd, "text.txt");

    // no redirection
    fork_pipes(cmd, NULL);

    // another example with a longer pipe 
    {
        char *cmd1[] = {"echo", "hello world", NULL};
        char *cmd2[] = {"tee", NULL};
        char *cmd3[] = {"tee", NULL};
        char *cmd4[] = {"tr", "lo", "10", NULL};

        char **cmd[] = {cmd1, cmd2, cmd3, cmd4, NULL};

        // redirected to redirection.txt
        fork_pipes(cmd, "redirection.txt");

        // no redirected
        fork_pipes(cmd, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As already pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478392/redirection-at-the-end-of-the-pipe-c-shell/47478908#comment81926358_47478392). You just need to call `pipe()` once in your example: The `pipe()` system call only needs to be called **once** for each *pipe operator* (i.e.: the `|` character) found in the compound command. For example, in the following command:

```
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 | cmd4
```

`pipe()` must be called exactly four times, since there are four *pipe operators*.

Comment: I tried following the comment in the way I attached to the question, but it doesn't work